# Saving a File in an Atom Text Editor Folder

Tags: python, image, file-upload, atom-editor, chromebook

This is my first time on stack overflow. I am a beginner python coder and I use the Atom text editor. I am currently learning from a book called PythonCrashCourse by Eric Matthes (second edition) and is developing a practice-project called Alien Invasion. I am currently stuck on saving a file of a spaceship image into a folder named "images" within my text editor. I have an ASUS chromebook. The file I am trying to save is called ship.bmp and the book instructions say "Make a folder called images inside your main alien_invasion project folder. Save the file ship.bmp in the images folder." I have the ship.bmp file saved but I just don't know how to transport it into a file within my text editor "images" folder. I have been stuck on this for quite a while and I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some advice. Thanks!

Comment: Open your file explorer and move the file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have the `ship.bmp` file **downloaded** somewhere on your computer. You then would need to *move it into your project folder*. I think that the easiest way for you to navigate through the files you have is to go to your `"Files"` app in the Chromebook. You should look through your **Downloads** folder for the `ship.bmp` after you download it and manually move it into the project folder that you are working on. You should be able to open your project folder and place the `ship.bmp` file inside the **"images" folder**.